# Sort out this Excel Filter Formula

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

I have Data table like this
I want sort above **25%** Point Percentage from the Year **2022** and Team **Arizona**

Note Table Name as : _master
I used this formula,

```
=filter(_master,(_master[Year]=2022)*(_master[Team]="Arozona")*(_master[Point]>=25%))
```

but it return no error

| Year | Team | NAME | No. | Pos | Ht | Wt | Point |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | New Orleans | Paulson Adebo | 29 | CB | 6-1 | 192 | 15% |
| 2022 | Arizona | Zach Allen | 94 | DE | 6-4 | 281 | 33% |
| 2022 | Arizona | Kiko Alonso | 47 | OLB | 6-3 | 239 | 20% |
| 2022 | Arizona | Stephen Anderson | 89 | TE | 6-2 | 230 | 39% |
| 2022 | Arizona | Josh Andrews | 68 | G | 6-2 | 298 | 23% |
| 2019 | Arizona | Marcell Ateman | 84 | WR | 6-4 | 215 | 39% |
| 2019 | Arizona | Andre Baccellia | 82 | WR | 5-10 | 175 | 47% |
| 2019 | Arizona | Budda Baker | 3 | S | 5-10 | 195 | 2% |
| 2017 | New Orleans | Kawaan Baker | 87 | WR | 6-1 | 215 | 40% |
| 2017 | Arizona | Darrell Baker Jr. | 31 | CB | 6-1 | 190 | 16% |
| 2017 | New Orleans | Zack Baun | 53 | LB | 6-3 | 225 | 24% |
| 2017 | Arizona | Kelvin Beachum | 68 | OL | 6-3 | 308 | 22% |
| 2017 | Arizona | Eno Benjamin | 26 | RB | 5-9 | 207 | 13% |
| 2016 | New Orleans | Josh Black | 57 | DT | 6-3 | 290 | 20% |
| 2016 | Arizona | Victor Bolden | 38 | WR | 5-8 | 178 | 21% |
| 2016 | New Orleans | Ian Book | 16 | QB | 6-0 | 206 | 8% |
| 2016 | Arizona | Breon Borders | 21 | CB | 6-0 | 189 | 11% |

Comment: I have shared sample data only. Each team has 10+ players with points above 25%. I want to return only the top 6 players.

Comment: Points may vary by year and team. I'd like an Excel formula for this.

Comment: There is a typing mistake. Formula should be working: `=FILTER(_Master,(_Master[Year]=2022)*(_Master[Team]="Arizona")*(_Master[Point]>=25%))` instead of `Arozona` it should be `Arizona` and hence why you are getting the error.

Comment: To return top six players you could do this btw: `=TAKE(SORT(FILTER(_Master,(_Master[Year]=2022)*(_Master[Team]="Arizona")*(_Master[Point]>=25%)),8,-1),6)`

Answer (score 0):

To return `Top 6` players one could use the following:

[image]

---

```
=TAKE(SORT(FILTER(_Master,(_Master[Year]=2022)*(_Master[Team]="Arizona")*(_Master[Point]>=25%)),8,-1),6)
```

---

Comment: check this [link](https://imgur.com/0FJ3TTW)

Comment: the same formula working in another data table

Comment: You download above link

Comment: The formula in the worksheet is working correctly, it correctly gets data for the year 2019 & Yoksam–tashiding, as well as `>.5` but in the data for the year and cons there is no `>.5` all less so returns blank. Check **[here](https://imgur.com/gallery/FYBLtZe)**

Comment: You may change the value, it return the blank only

Comment: Finally i Got it... just remove **#VALUE**

Comment: This works I found there is `#VALUE!` error: `=IFERROR(INDEX(SORT(FILTER(_main_all,IFERROR((_main_all[Year]=M2)*(N2=_main_all[Cons])*(_main_all[Votes P]>0.5),0),""),6,-1),SEQUENCE(12),{3,4,2,5,6,8,10,9}),"")`